Nginx not loading image on a static HTML page
I have several frontend websites running via Nginx reverse proxy using server blocks. All of these websites are stored in their own directories within the /opt/ folder. I also have an /opt/status/ folder, which contains HTML files representing maintenance pages.
Here is an example of one of my site blocks:
 server_name mydomain.com;

   root /opt/status;

   if ($allowed_country = no) {
      return 444;
   }

   if (-f $document_root/east.ca.html) {
      return 503;
   }
   error_page 503 @maintenance;

   location / {
      proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:3070/;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   }

   location @maintenance {
      rewrite ^(.*)$ /east.ca.html break;
   }
}

So if east.ca.html exists within /opt/status, this page is served to the user instead of proxying them to the web application. The idea is that a .disabled extension is appended to the end of the file to "disable" the maintenance page.
This maintenance page loads fine, the issue is that this HTML page has a linked image. This image does not load. I have tried referencing the image the following ways:
<img src="logo.png" ... />
<img src="./logo.png" ... />
<img src="/logo.png" ... />
<img src="/opt/status/logo.png" ... />

None of the above worked to actually load the image.
What changes need to be made so that nginx can properly load the image?
The html file has the same permissions as the logo, so I know that is not the issue.

When file east.ca.html exists then ALL requests (including requests for images) are rewritten to that file.
